WinUI3 FindWindow() keep returning 0x0000000000000000
I am building two app using winui3C# as sender app and receiver app.
In sender app, I used findwindow() and send message() at buttonclicked event.
In receiver app, I want to show notification when sender app send message.
Problem is Findwindow() result is "0x0000000000000000".
Any idea what I left to do something in this? Thank you.
Here my sender code
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const uint WM_USER = 0x0400; // Custom message range for user-defined messages
private const int WM_MY_MESSAGE = (int)(WM_USER + 1); // Custom message identifier

 private async void SendMessageButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         // Find the window handle of the receiver app
         IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "com.receiver"); //namespace of receiver app

         if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
         {
             // Send a message to the receiver app
             SendMessage(hWnd, (uint)WM_MY_MESSAGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
             await ShowMessageDialog("Message sent to the receiver app.");
         }
         else
         {
             await ShowMessageDialog("Receiver app window not found.");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         await ShowMessageDialog("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }

my receiver:
 private const int WM_MY_MESSAGE = 0x0400 + 1; // Custom message identifier
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    RegisterWindowMessage();
}
private void RegisterWindowMessage()
{
    // Register the custom window message
    RegisterWindowMessage("WM_MY_MESSAGE");
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

private void Dispatcher_AcceleratorKeyActivated(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    // Handle the custom window message
    if (args.KeyStatus.RepeatCount == WM_MY_MESSAGE)
    {
        ShowNotification("Message received from sender app.");
    }
}

private async void ShowNotification(string message)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}


FindWindow(null, "com.receiver") should work fine (return a non null handle) if you're looking for an opened WinUI3 window which Title property has been set to "com.receiver".

@SimonMourier thz! I checked my Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window.Current and result is null. I don't know why but this may be the problem of FindWindow didn' work.

Window.Current Property:Desktop apps always return null for this property.
If you want to retrieve a window handle in the winui3， I suggest you should use GetWindowHandle instead of findWindow. Refer to the Doc: Retrieve a window handle
